# ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.segment is not a function from GEE LandTrendr

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, landsat-8, landtrendr

I am working on a GEE project on a LandTrendr model for California looking at wildfires in the LA region from 2013-2023 using Landsat 8. This class involved no GEE and yet we need to use it. This is the last code of it

```
 // Define collection parameters
var startYear = 2010;
var endYear = 2023;
var startDay = '06-20';
var endDay = '09-20';
var index = 'NBR';
var maskThese = ['cloud', 'shadow']; // Including 'shadow'

// Load the county boundaries dataset
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("TIGER/2016/Counties");

// Filter Counties to get LA County - filter by GEOID = 06037
var LACounty = table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('GEOID','06037'));

// Get the geometry of the LA County
var aoi = LACounty.geometry();

// Define landtrendr parameters
var runParams = { 
  maxSegments: 6,
  spikeThreshold: 0.9,
  vertexCountOvershoot: 3,
  preventOneYearRecovery: true,
  recoveryThreshold: 0.25,
  pvalThreshold: 0.05,
  bestModelProportion: 0.75,
  minObservationsNeeded: 6
};

// Load Landsat 8 collection, filter by date and AOI
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
  .filterBounds(aoi)
  .filterDate(startYear + '-01-01', endYear + '-12-31')
  .map(function(image) {
    return image.clip(aoi);
  });

// Function to mask clouds using NDVI
var maskClouds = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI'); // Calculate NDVI
  var cloudMask = ndvi.lt(0.8); // Set a threshold for cloud identification based on NDVI
  return image.updateMask(cloudMask.not()); // Inverting cloud mask
};

// Function to mask shadows using NDSI
var maskShadows = function(image) {
  var ndsi = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B6']).rename('NDSI'); // Calculate NDSI
  var shadowMask = ndsi.lt(0.5); // Set a threshold for shadow identification based on NDSI
  return image.updateMask(shadowMask.not());
};

// Apply cloud and shadow masking to the collection
var maskedCollection = collection.map(maskClouds).map(maskShadows);

// Function to prepare data for LandTrendr
var prepareData = function(image) {
  return image.select(['B[1-7]']); // Selecting bands B1 to B7 for LandTrendr
};

// Prepare data and run LandTrendr
var preparedCollection = maskedCollection.map(prepareData);
var ltResult = ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.segment(preparedCollection, runParams);

// Extract change map layers
var changeImg = ltResult.select(index);

// Define a palette for visualization
var palette = [
  '00FF00', '32CD32', '66CDAA', '8FBC8F', '9ACD32', // Greens
  'BDB76B', 'DAA520', 'FFA500', 'FF7F50', 'FF6347', // Yellows and Oranges
  'FF4500', 'FF0000', 'CD5C5C', 'B22222', '8B0000' // Reds
];

var vizParms = {
  min: 0,
  max: 1,
  palette: palette
};

// Display the change attribute map
Map.centerObject(aoi, 11);
Map.addLayer(changeImg, vizParms, 'LandTrendr Change');

// Export the image to the server-side first
Export.image.toAsset({
  image: changeImg.clip(aoi).unmask(0).short(),
  description: 'lt-gee_growth_map',
  assetId: 'users/yourUserName/lt-gee_growth_map' // Change to your asset path
});
```

This error is occurring constantly:

> "Line 62: ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.segment is not a
> function".

Any one able to modify the code and make it run?